# Cast vimeo video with Android

Tags: android-mediaplayer, vimeo, vimeo-api, vimeo-player

I'm developing an app which gets the videos from Vimeo.
How can I cast the video on Miracast/Chromecast?
I'm using the media player.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to cast videos from Vimeo, you will need the MP4 links; you would be able to construct MediaInfo objects with these video file links for use with the Cast Companion Library or directly with the Cast SDK. Vimeo provides PRO users with MP4 links to their *own* videos. See [Video File](https://github.com/vimeo/vimeo-networking-java/blob/dev/vimeo-networking/src/main/java/com/vimeo/networking/model/VideoFile.java) in the Vimeo Java/Android networking library for more info on what you would use to construct the MediaInfo objects.

You could also deeplink into the Vimeo Android App, have it play your video, and at that point users can use the cast button on the Vimeo player to cast the video. Check out the official [Vimeo deeplink helper library](https://github.com/vimeo/vimeo-deeplink-android).

Answer (score 0):

Im getting a error when I cast the vimeo video to my TV.

Im using the account pro, owner of the video.
This is my url `http://player.vimeo.com/external/161670290.hd.mp4?s=9f861403dd0f...c034bfde2dae2&profile_id=119&oauth2_token_id=42...082`

My tv said that the file type isnt valid.
Checking with other video types, with hls I get the error invalid audio codec.
Im using LG WEBOS with connect sdk, its working with a normal mp4 like `http://www.sample-videos.com/video/mp4/720/big_buck_bunny_720p_1mb.mp4`
Whats the problem?

Comment: I am not familiar with LG WEBOS, but I would suspect the issue lies within that SDK, as the Vimeo URL you provided works with Google Cast.

Comment: Yes, the problem is my LG, cause connect sdk and the vimeo url its working on chromecast & apple tv.